# Test with If condition From toast Message

Tags: android, android-intent

I just want to test the toast message string

> Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "" + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

something like that

```
if ( response ="Success" ) {
openActivity1();
}else {
openActivity2();
}
```

I tested it with an if condition like that and it did not work for me.

Can anybody give me a suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Use `==` operator in `if` statement. And look for some `equals` method to compare strings.

Answer (score 0):

use this instead of yours:

```
if (response.equals("Success")) {
openActivity1();
}else {
openActivity2();
}
```

Comment: it accept the condition but the activity does not open

Comment: how do you start your activity? use this: startActivity(new Intent(context,MainActivity2.class));

Answer (score 0):

to test a String with other String u have to use  Object.equals(Object) and not '=' .

Edited this how to start the Activity

```
   if (response.equals("Success")){
       Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
       startActivity(i);
     }
```

This will work prefect

Comment: it accept the condition but the activity does not open